# Can't use object as parameter in WebAPI get request

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# class called `DateParams` defined as follows:

```
    public class DateParams {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller I have a `Get` method defined as:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/myreport/{dateParams}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]DateParams dateParams) {}
```

I'm calling the controller from Angular as follows:

```
  myService.GetMyReport = function (dateParams) {
      return $http.get(serviceURLRoot + 'api/myreport/', dateParams, { withCredentials: true }).success(function (data) {
      });
  };
```

I keep getting the error: `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.`

I've verified that dateParams matches the structure defined server side and it's properly populated. Similar questions on StackOverflow refer to using `[FromUri]` in the controller method's parameter list but this hasn't resolved the issue. I tried `[FromBody]` as well but it also fails, probably because `Get` requests can't have bodies.

Comment: You could do some tests/debug: 1. Try to access the url directly from the browser (as it is a GET request should have no problem on it) or using postman. If you have success doing it, it means the problem is in your javascript, otherwise you should investigate your WebAPI code. After doing this tests please update the question to provide more info. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. This has worked for me in the past

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[Route("api/myreport/{dateParams}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]DateParams dateParams) {}
```

You are probably using `System.Web.Mvc` namespace

Comment: I've verified that I am not using `System.Web.Mvc`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a couple of times with DateTime format, a better approach might be to define them as string in your object and parse it to a date in your code/model.

For testing, try the "string" and see if that works, then if you still need to have the model defined with DateTime type, there are a few rules to be followed.